# Integer solutions to a two variable equation.

Tags: number-theory, integer-lattices

For $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, show the only integer solutions to

$f(m,n) = \displaystyle \frac{3^m(2^n+1)-2^{m+n}}{2^{m+n}-3^{m+1}}$

are $f(1, 2) = -7$, $f(0, 1) = -1$, and $f(0, 2) = 1$. More importantly, show that $f(m, n) \notin \mathbb{N}$ for $m, n >0$.

Comment: You could improve the statement of your question:  "For m, n.... show that the only integer value of f(m,n) EQUIV ... are f(1,2) = -7, ..."

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**
for $m=1$, by induction on $n$ we have, $f(1,n)\not\in\mathbb{N}$. suppose that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(k,n)\not\in\mathbb{N}$ then for $m=k+1$ we have :
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\qquad\displaystyle \frac{3^{k+1}(2^n+1)-2^{k+1+n}}{2^{k+1+n}-3^{k+2}}\not\in\mathbb{N}$$
because, by induction on $n$, if $f(k+1,l+1)\in\mathbb{N}$, then we have :
$$3^{k+1}(2^{l+1}+1)-2^{k+l+2}=(2^{k+l+2}-3^{k+2})a$$
Contradiction.

Comment: I found something different. Rearrange the top into $(2^n(3^m - 2^m) + 3^m)/(2^{m+2} - 3^{m+1})$. By difference of powers, this is $(3^m + 2^n 3^{m-1} + 2^{n+1} 3^{m-2} + \cdots + 3 2^{m+n-2} + 2^{m+n-1})/(2^{m+n} - 3^{m+1})$. This form is related to cycles of the Collatz transformation. If $p_1$ has this form, then $p_1$ is a cycle whose first transformation has $n$ divisions by $2$, and all subsequent transformations have $1$. Thus, $p_1$ is an element of a $1$-cycle (a cycle with one local minimum), and the only one cycle corresponds to $p_1 = 1$, which only works with $(m, n) = (0, 1)$.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I follow your reasoning: whence comes the $2^{l+2}$ on the left hand side of $3^{k+1}(2^{l+2}) - 2^{k+l+2} = (2^{k+l+2}-3^{k+2})a$?

Comment: With induction on $n$. if $f(k+1,l)\not\in\mathbb{N}$ (induction hypothesis) then we must proof that $f(k+1,l+1)\not\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: $2^{\ell + 1} + 1 \neq 2^{\ell + 2}$

Comment: Yes. I did a mistake.